# jQuery event values are not captured when shifting to new destination

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the original form

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form">
    <table class='header_tbl' style="background:none !important;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Amount(RM)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><span class='qty_1'></span><input type='hidden' name='total_qty' value=''></td>
                <td><span class='total'></span><input type='hidden' name='total' value=''></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <!--membership-->
            <tr id="membership" class="no_show">
                <td><span class="mem_1"></span></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><span class="mem_2"></span></td>
                <td><span class="mem_3"></span><input type='hidden' name='mem' value='10'><br/><input type='hidden' name='email_2' value=''><input type='hidden' name='ic_add' value=''></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="comm" class="no_show">
                <td>Commision (x%)</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><span class='comm'><?php echo $discount;?></span>%<input type='hidden' name='comm' value='<?php echo $discount;?>'></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="no_show">
                <td>Total Payment</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><span class='grand'></span><input type='hidden' name='grand' value=''></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='add_here'>
            </tr>
            <!--cust info starts-->
            <tr class="no_show">
                <td colspan="3"><input type='hidden' name='cust_id' id='cust_id' value=''><br/><input type='hidden' name='cust_email' id='cust_email' value=''></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="no_show">
                <td colspan="3"><input type='hidden' name='cust_name' id='cust_name' value=''></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <!--membership-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><input type='hidden' name='mem_id' value='<?php echo $membership;?>'></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><input type='hidden' name='mem_name' value='<?php echo $username;?>'></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <!--membership ends-->
            <!--cust info ends-->
            <!--membership ends-->
            <tr id="replace_this">
                <td></td>
                <td class="cancel"><input type="button" name='cancel' id="cancel" value="CANCEL"/></td>
                <td class="cash"><input type="submit" name='submit' id="cash" value="CASH"/></td>
                <td class="checkout"><input type="button" name='checkout' id="checkout" value="CHECK OUT"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```

All rows between `<tbody></tbody>` appended via jquery

I'm shifting this entire form into new destination like this:

```
$('#left_col #cart_form2').html($('#cart_form').html());
```

The new form's destination has the following structure:

```
<div class='small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns' id='left_col'>

       <div class="container">
         <form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form2"> </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

The output after shifted to new destination is:

[image]

The value in the textbox are empty in the new destination.How do I get the values when shifting? I tried cloning but that doesn't work here well for me.

EDIT:

```
 console.log("cart= "+$('#cart_form').html());

<table class="header_tbl" style="background:none !important;">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Amount(RM)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

    <tbody><tr id="2"><th class="product">Slimming Tea<input type="hidden" name="catalog_name[]" value="Slimming Tea"></th><td class="price">RM <span class="pp_2">25</span><input type="hidden" id="2_price[]" name="price[]" value="25" class="price2"></td><td class="qty_2"><input type="text" name="qty" style="width:50px;height:20px;margin:10px auto;" value="" onchange="subTotal2(&quot;2&quot;)"><input type="hidden" id="2_qty2[]" name="qty2[]" value=""><span class="show_2"></span></td><td class="sub_total">25</td><td><img src="http://emall.3pteb.my/pos_system/img/del.png" style="width:15px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="del_this(&quot;2&quot;)"></td></tr><tr id="4"><th class="product">Karipap Pusing Ayu<input type="hidden" name="catalog_name[]" value="Karipap Pusing Ayu"></th><td class="price">RM <span class="pp_4">8</span><input type="hidden" id="4_price[]" name="price[]" value="8" class="price2"></td><td class="qty_4"><input type="text" name="qty" style="width:50px;height:20px;margin:10px auto;" value="" onchange="subTotal2(&quot;4&quot;)"><input type="hidden" id="4_qty2[]" name="qty2[]" value=""><span class="show_4"></span></td><td class="sub_total">16</td><td><img src="http://emall.3pteb.my/pos_system/img/del.png" style="width:15px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="del_this(&quot;4&quot;)"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    <tr>
    <td>Total</td><td></td><td><span class="qty_1">3</span><input type="hidden" name="total_qty" value=""></td><td><span class="total">41</span><input type="hidden" name="total" value="41"></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <!--membership-->
     <tr id="membership" class="no_show">
    <td><span class="mem_1"></span></td><td></td><td><span class="mem_2"></span></td><td><span class="mem_3"></span><input type="hidden" name="mem" value="10"><br><input type="hidden" name="email_2" value=""><input type="hidden" name="ic_add" value=""></td><td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="comm" class="no_show">
    <td>Commision (x%)</td><td></td><td></td><td><span class="comm">20</span>%<input type="hidden" name="comm" value="20"></td><td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="no_show">
    <td>Total Payment</td><td></td><td></td><td><span class="grand">41</span><input type="hidden" name="grand" value="41"></td><td></td>
    </tr>
   <tr id="add_here">
   </tr>
    <!--cust info starts-->
  <tr class="no_show">
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" value=""><br><input type="hidden" name="cust_email" id="cust_email" value=""></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no_show">
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="cust_name" id="cust_name" value=""></td><td></td>
    </tr>
     <!--membership-->
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input type="hidden" name="mem_id" value="123"></td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input type="hidden" name="mem_name" value="QIZLAF MARKETING"></td><td></td>
      </tr>
    <!--membership ends-->
    <!--cust info ends-->
    <!--membership ends-->
    <tr id="replace_this">
    <td></td>
    <td class="cancel"><input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="CANCEL"></td>
    <td class="cash"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="cash" value="CASH"></td>
    <td class="checkout"><input type="button" name="checkout" id="checkout" value="CHECK OUT"></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>



</table>
```

Comment: What does console.log($('#cart_form').html()) show? What do you mean on "shifting"? What was the code you tried for cloning? Moving wit $.append() is not good?

Comment: @Gavriel, I added the output in my post

Comment: Is requirement to have two forms having same values ?

Comment: all the value=""-s are empty, aren't?

Comment: @Keren Would create duplicate `id`s in document ?

Comment: Yes it would anyway. The only 2 solutions I can think of: not to have any id-s in the original form, or not to copy, but move it by appending the original DOM elements to the new form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, getting relevant `:input` value and setting it to the new ones:

```
$('#left_col #cart_form2').html($('#cart_form').html()).find(':input').val(function(i){
     return $('#cart_form').find(':input').eq(i).val();
}).end().find('[id]').attr('id', function(_, id){ return id + "_2"});
```

But it looks terribely expensive...

To keep bound event/data on children elements, you should use:

```
$('#cart_form').clone(true).replaceAll('#left_col #cart_form2').attr('id', 'cart_form2').find(':input').val(function(i) {
  return $('#cart_form').find(':input').eq(i).val();
}).end().find('[id]').attr('id', function(_, id) {
  return id + "_2"
});
```

Comment: Would this create duplicate `id`s in document ?

Comment: @A. Wolff How does your brain work man... The thing with the `id`'s. Elegant. _/\\_

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I'm drinking coffee... **.**_0

Comment: This does what it says on the tin... but beware that it'll still lose any bound events attached to the form, and generating new IDs will break any code that was depending on those original IDs.    It's an elegant way to do something that almost certainly shouldn't be done in other words

Comment: @DanielBeck Ya that's correct. We should use `.clone(true)` but i'll be more desastrous regarding perf even in most case shouldn't be an issue. I'll update answer to take events/data bound into account

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution can use the clone plus appendTo and each function to replace the ids and values.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#btn').click(function(e) {
    $('#cart_form').clone(true).appendTo('#left_col #cart_form2').find('[id]:not(:input), :input:not([value=""])').each(function(index, element) {
      if (element.id != "")
        this.id = element.id + '_2';
      if (element.value !== undefined)
        this.value = element.value;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form">
    <table class='header_tbl' style="background:none !important;">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Amount(RM)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>

        <tr>
            <td>Total</td><td></td><td><span class='qty_1'></span><input type='hidden' name='total_qty' value=''></td><td><span class='total'></span><input type='hidden' name='total' value=''></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <!--membership-->
        <tr id="membership" class="no_show">
            <td><span class="mem_1"></span></td><td></td><td><span class="mem_2"></span></td><td><span class="mem_3"></span><input type='hidden' name='mem' value='10'><br/><input type='hidden' name='email_2' value=''><input type='hidden' name='ic_add' value=''></td><td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="comm" class="no_show">
            <td>Commision (x%)</td><td></td><td></td><td><span class='comm'><?php echo $discount;?></span>%<input type='hidden' name='comm' value='<?php echo $discount;?>'></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="no_show">
            <td>Total Payment</td><td></td><td></td><td><span class='grand'></span><input type='hidden' name='grand' value=''></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='add_here'>
        </tr>
        <!--cust info starts-->
        <tr class="no_show">
            <td colspan="3"><input type='hidden' name='cust_id' id='cust_id' value=''><br/><input type='hidden' name='cust_email' id='cust_email' value=''></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="no_show">
            <td colspan="3"><input type='hidden' name='cust_name' id='cust_name' value=''></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <!--membership-->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type='hidden' name='mem_id' value='<?php echo $membership;?>'></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type='hidden' name='mem_name' value='<?php echo $username;?>'></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <!--membership ends-->
        <!--cust info ends-->
        <!--membership ends-->
        <tr id="replace_this">
            <td></td>
            <td class="cancel"><input type="button" name='cancel' id="cancel" value="CANCEL"/></td>
            <td class="cash"><input type="submit" name='submit' id="cash" value="CASH"/></td>
            <td class="checkout"><input type="button" name='checkout' id="checkout" value="CHECK OUT"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>



    </table>
</form>
<div class='small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns' id='left_col'>
    <div class="container">
-----------NEW FORM-----------------
        <form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form2"> </form>
-----------END NEW FORM-----------------
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Approach creates duplicate `id`s in document ?

Comment: Beware, you are nesting `form` here even the DOM parser would remove it

Comment: @Keren I'm sorry. Could you try to click the button "Click Me" now and let me know? I used a button to insert my code, but you need only the inner code. Please, click only once on the button